# Submitting form with ajax and formspree using VuesJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, vue.js

I'm trying to submit a form using formspree I get two different errors. When I try to submit the form after I refresh the page I get an error on a new page saying

> Cannot POST /Contact

When I go back and try to submit the form again I get an error in the console saying:

> POST https://formspree.io/sheabathandbody@mail.com 400 () jquery.min.js:4
>
> send @ jquery.min.js:4
>
> ajax @ jquery.min.js:4
>
> (anonymous) @ main.js:8
>
> dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3
>
> r.handle @ jquery.min.js:3

I've used this method/code to submit my forms before so i don't know what the problem could be

Contact.vue form

```
<form id="contact" name="contact-form" method="post" action = "">
    <fieldset>
      <input placeholder="Your name" name="name" type="text" id="name" tabindex="1" required="required">
     </fieldset>
     <fieldset>
        <input placeholder="Your Email Address" name="email" id="email" type="email" tabindex="2" required="required">
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
         <input placeholder="Your Phone Number (optional)" type="tel" tabindex="3">
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
        <textarea placeholder="Type your message here...." tabindex="5" name="message" id="message" required="required"></textarea>
       </fieldset>
       <fieldset>
         <button name="submit" type="submit" id="submit_btn" >Submit</button>
       </fieldset>
</form>
```

Here's my main.js

```
(function($) {
$(window).on("load", function() {
// Contact form
var form = $("#contact");
form.submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var form_status = $('<div class="form_status"></div>');
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://formspree.io/sheabathandbody@mail.com",
    method: "POST",
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    dataType: "json",
    beforeSend: function() {
      form.prepend(
        form_status
          .html(
            '<p><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Email is sending...</p>'
          )
          .fadeIn()
      );
    }
  }).done(function(data) {
    form_status
      .html(
        '<p class="text-success">Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch.</p>'
      )
      .delay(3000)
      .fadeOut();
  });
 });
});
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Guess this has nothing to do with VueJS since it does not use at all vue in that chunks of code you shared, this is pure jQuery.

Said that, the problem sending the form was because you were not listening correctly to submit event.

```
form.on('submit', function () { ... })
```

On the other hand, ajax call is not working correctly; you should check documentation of formspree.io and correct it.

Check next code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Contact form
  var form = $("#contact");
  form.on('submit', function(event) {
    alert('Hola hola. This is working now!');
    event.preventDefault();
    var form_status = $('<div class="form_status"></div>');
    $.ajax({
      url: "https://formspree.io/sheabathandbody@mail.com",
      method: "POST",
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      dataType: "json",
      beforeSend: function() {
        form.prepend(
          form_status
          .html(
            '<p><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Email is sending...</p>'
          )
          .fadeIn()
        );
      }
    }).done(function(data) {
      form_status
        .html(
          '<p class="text-success">Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch.</p>'
        )
        .delay(3000)
        .fadeOut();
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="contact" name="contact-form" method="post" action="">
  <fieldset>
    <input placeholder="Your name" name="name" type="text" id="name" tabindex="1" value="blah" required="required">
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <input value="email@email.com" placeholder="Your Email Address" name="email" id="email" type="email" tabindex="2" required="required">
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <input value="123123123" placeholder="Your Phone Number (optional)" type="tel" tabindex="3">
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <textarea placeholder="Type your message here...." tabindex="5" name="message" id="message" required="required">Damn</textarea>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <button name="submit" type="submit" id="submit_btn">Submit</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: I still get the same errors after adding changes...that's why I think it might have something to do with VueJS

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method for example postNow.

```
  methods: {

   postNow() {
      const link = "https://formspree.io/sheabathandbody@mail.com"
     var data = new FormData();
     data.append('_replyto',this.email)
     data.append('message',this.message)
  
     this.axios.post(link,data , {
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
      },
    // body: data,
    }).then(res =>{
       console.log("response ===" ,res)
       this.email = "" ;this.message=""; //don't forget to create your data
    }).catch(err =>{
      console.log(err)
    });
  }
},
```

And in your template you can use the simple HTML form with few tweaks ofc,

```
<form  @submit.prevent="postNow" method="POST" >
          <label>
            Your email:
            <input type="email" name="_replyto" v-model="email" />
          </label>
          <label>
            Your message:
            <textarea name="message" v-model="message"></textarea>
          </label>


          <button type="submit">Send</button>
        </form>
```